# SystemML build failed on MacOS

Tags: java, scala, maven, build, systemml

I recently started to contribute in **SystemML**. When I tried build the systemml source by maven in my macbook, build fails everytime.

It seems it has some issue with scala but I cannot figure it out.
Tried changing scala version, reinstalling sbt, cleaning the maven locale repo (~/.m2 dir) as well, still has no luck.

I used systemml 1.1.0 source on macOS high sierra version 10.13.1 with Java 9.0.4 and maven 3.5.2.

The error was looked like this:

```
[ERROR] error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:31)
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:64)
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[ERROR]     at scala_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:164)
[ERROR]     at scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 09:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-27T23:57:34+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project systemml: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project systemml: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute (ScalaMojoSupport.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:147)
    at scala_maven_executions.JavaMainCallerByFork.run (JavaMainCallerByFork.java:100)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:161)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute (ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The full built code can see here. https://gist.github.com/mpgovinda/f9a759d3fb3a8e1cc8e69b6431bbb2f2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is due to an incompatibility of the current SystemML Scala version (2.11.8) utilized by the scala-maven-plugin with Java 9. If I use Java 9.0.4 on macOS High Sierra with Maven 3.5.2, I see the same error if I try to build using `mvn clean package`.

If I switch to Java 8 (1.8.0_60), SystemML builds correctly for me.